# Insert a character (-) if result is empty

Tags: php

I have this following code:

```
 $result = $conn->query($query);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
      { 
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$row['total']) . "</td>";  
  echo "</tr>"; 
   }
```

What I try to do is if the output is empty, then insert (-) character. Only if there is no value output.

I tried this:

```
 $result = $conn->query($query);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 $total = $total ?? "" ?: "-";

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
      { 
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $total . "</td>";   
  echo "</tr>"; 
   }
```

this replaces all outputs with (-). 
How can I achieve this? please. thank you for your help!

Note that if the result of `preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$row['total'])`  is empty, then it should insert (-) character.

The inputs are like this:

```
100.
80.
70.
etc
```

Expected output would be something like this:

```
Total
100
90
-
80
70
-
10
```

Comment: @Roshan you mean certainly `if`. But yeah, you don't need regex for that. In your for loop, check for the value of `$row['total']`

Comment: We have the desired output, but can we have input sample for `$row['total']` ?

Comment: Then add another if else statement inside while loop, check if `$row['total']` has value then cast the value of that, else replace it with `"-"`.

Something like this:
  `if($row['total'] == " "){ echo $row['total']; }else{ echo "-"; }`

Comment: I added some input sample in the post. thanks.

Comment: What does a non-numeric row have as a value?  Empty space? `null`? Something else?  Do you need a descending for loop? If there is no row for 90, then how would expect output for that position?  Maybe you'd like to add/UNION some static rows into your query.  We don't know.

Comment: Not sure of the logic behind `$total = $total ?? "" ?: "-";`, surely this would shorten to `$total = $total ?? "-";` if $total contained nulls.

Comment: Are the values alway integers followed by a dot?

Comment: yes, they are. I can remove the dots in mysql query. but I don't want to do this for other reasons.

Comment: So `rtrim($row['title'], '.')` will do then.  What are you doing to handle missing rows?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. there are no missing rows.

Comment: @Max you can trim or regexp in mysql query

Comment: @Pritamkumar, thank you. I needed a php solution.

Comment: i think you should try using in  database query as it will fasten your code execution time

Comment: This page is loaded with answers that should not work with the sample data, yet they are all upvoted.  Very disappointing for this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check total value and replace it if it is empty. For example:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
  $total = empty($row['total']) ? '-' : preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$row['total']);
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $total . "</td>";  
  echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: Why using RegEx?

Comment: If zero is a valid number, this solution will damage the data.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use case statement in mysql

```
SELECT (CASE
    WHEN total regexp '^[0-9]+$'  THEN total

    ELSE '-' END) as total
FROM `tbl_order`
```

where `regexp '^[0-9]+$'` matches whether  variable `total` is `numeric` or not

by using **case** we check if **total** is numeric then print `total` otherwise `-`

Comment: This cannot work because the OP's data has trailing dots.

Comment: And we were never told what the non-qualifying rows hold.

Comment: if  OP's data has trailing dots we can use decimal reg exp `'^[0-9]+$'  '^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$'` then using `ceil(total)`

Comment: Your regex is becoming a mess.  I refer an SQL solution for this task, but making a clean solution would require the OP clarifying what is in the table column.